# SVN does not resolve symbolic link in the path of a file

Tags: windows, svn, cygwin

I have a directory checked out form svn. This directory structure is:

```
dir_from_svn:
    - file.cpp
```

And I want to check the status of this file from another directory that has a symbolic link to the "dir_from_svn"

```
svn status  dir_from_svn_slink/file.cpp
```

where

```
    dir_from_svn_slink -> ../dir_from_svn
```

The issue is that SVN does not resolve the symbolic link.

```
   svn: warning: W155010: The node 'C:\home\name\test\dir_from_svn_slink\file.cpp' was not found.
```

However, issuing the svn command with the value of the symbolic link works fine:

```
    svn status  ../dir_from_svn/file.cpp
```

gives

```
    M    C:\home\name\test\..\dir_from_svn\file.cpp
```

I'm working on Cygwin. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I used a workaround using Perl script: I check on the path of the file if it is a symbolic link or not. If it is a symbolic link, I resolve it using the Perl function "readlink()". Hence, I use this resolved value to construct the file path and check for its status using SVN.

Answer (score 0):

1. "symbolic link" in OS is *OS-specific* in implementation and, thus, isn't really "portable"
2. Due to p. 1 using plain `ln -s` isn't recommended for compability
3. SVN have own **supported naturally** way of linking files/directories - SVN externals